# Twitter Bootstrap Carousel indicators active state not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap latest version and I have this markup for my carousel:

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
        <h1>test</h1>
         <p>lorem ipsum sit dolor amet</p>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
       <h1>test</h1>
         <p>lorem ipsum sit dolor amet</p>
    </div>

  </div>


  <ol class="features">

    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active">Modular Compoents</li>

    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1">Demos</li>

  </ol>

</div>
```

and this JS:

```
$('.carousel').carousel({
  interval: false
})
```

The problem is that when I click on second indicator the "active" state class doesn't move to the second indicator, it stays on the first one but the carousel is working.

Here's a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/poluyevijulo/1/)

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this fiddle : http://www.bootply.com/kvASXvsXXV:

**HTML** :

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <h1>test</h1>
            <p>lorem ipsum sit dolor amet</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <h1>test</h1>
            <p>lorem ipsum sit dolor amet 222</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <ol class="carousel-indicators features">      // <------   LOOK HERE
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active">Modular Compoents</li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1">Demos</li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

You forgot to add class `carousel-indicators` to your `ol` tags.

And to display it, just hack the css as you want it... else : (width and height to 12px)....

```
.active{
    color:red;
}

  .carousel-indicators{
  position:relative;
      margin-top:2em;
 }

 .carousel-indicators li{
        display:block;
        width:auto !important;
        height:auto !important;
 }
```